For configuring an Elasticsearch cluster on nodes with non-fixed IPs, what should the instances.yml file look like?
Elasticsearch provides an example of creating a cluster via docker compose - the compose file, .env file and associated instructions shows 3 services, dependant on a config service.
I'm referencing this example to create an Elasticsearch cluster on a swarm (instead of docker-compose). I see in the setup task that certs are configured via an instances.yml file:
instances:
   - name: es01
     dns:
       - es01
       - localhost
     ip:
       - 127.0.0.1
   - name: es02
     dns:
       - es02
       - localhost
     ip:
       - 127.0.0.1
   - name: es03
     dns:
       - es03
       - localhost
     ip:
       - 127.0.0.1

In the context of a cluster deployed to docker compose, I understand that the elasticsearch cert utility will be able to generate self-signed certs and a ca in the context of 3 nodes that are all contactible on localhost.
What should this file look like when the IP addresses of the various nodes are NOT 127.0.0.1?
(or does this question make sense)?
From within, for example an es01 container, I will be able to resolve elasticsearch on the loopback address (localhost / 127.0.0.1). However the other hosts (es02 and es03) will not be resolvable.
In the case of Docker Swarm (or, I would guess, any container orchestration platform) the IP addresses of a particular container are not fixed. Does this matter?

This does seem to be correct, in that I can get nodes to talk to each other using certs configured via this file.
